# How to open pdf files in assets folder ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I am working on a **ionic 3** project and I want to open **pdf** files inside the **"assets/pdf"** folder.
I used ionic-native file opener for this. But it throws an error saying **file not found**

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { FileOpener } from '@ionic-native/file-opener';

constructor(private file: File, private fileOpener: FileOpener) { }

public openFile() {
    const url = "assets/pdf/unit1.pdf";
    this.fileOpener.open(this.file.applicationDirectory + url, 'application/pdf')
        .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
        .catch(e => {
          console.log('Error openening file', e);
        });
}
```

It seems like an error in the path. But I don't know how to use it.Anyone knows how to use this function?

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you manage to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

What I did to get past this issue was copy the file to externalCacheDirectory prior to opening it.

```
this.file.copyFile(this.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/assets/pdf/', this.filename, this.file.externalCacheDirectory, this.filename)
    .then( _ => {
        this.fileOpener.open(this.file.externalCacheDirectory + this.filename, 'application/pdf')
        .then( _ => {
            console.log('File opened');
        })
        .catch(e => console.log("Error opening file: " + JSON.stringify(e)));
     })
     .catch( e => {
        console.log("Error copying file: " + JSON.stringify(e));
     });
```

Comment: this solution will only works to android, since the property externalCacheDirectory exists only there.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you confirmed if the file is really in that path.
You can try to use Ionic Document Viewer, please take a look at this:
[Ionic Document Viewer](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/document-viewer/)
, should solve your problem, give it a try..